# Testng @Factory method fails when tied with a DataProvider

Tags: java, testng

I have a testng DataProvider and Factory annotated class that dynamically executes a test class based on various data provided by the data provider.

Here's the classes:

```
DataProvider
==================
@DataProvider (name="GenericDataProvider", parallel=true) 
public static Object[][] genericDP(Method method, ITestContext context) throws Exception{

    Map<String,String> arguments = DataProviderUtils.resolveDataProviderArguments(method);
    List<Map<String,String>> valList = null;

    if (arguments.containsKey("propFile")) {
        String file = arguments.get("propFile");
        InputStream stream = BaseDataProvider.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file);
        TestUtilities testUtil = new TestUtilities();
        valList = testUtil.parseXML(testUtil.getStringFromInputStream(stream), "dataset");
    }

    return new Object[][] { { valList } };
}

The Factory class
=====================
@Factory
@Test(dataProviderClass=BaseDataProvider.class, dataProvider="GenericDataProvider")
@DataProviderArguments({"propFile=psgITest.xml"} )
public void runMultipleAccountProvisioningTestsWithDifferentUniversityPartners(List<Map<String,String>> datasets) {

    String partner = null;
    String source = null;

    for (Map<String,String> dataset : datasets) {
        for (String data : dataset.keySet()) {
            if ("partner".equalsIgnoreCase(data)) {
                partner = dataset.get(data);
            } else if ("source".equalsIgnoreCase(data)) {
                source = dataset.get(data);
            }

            if (null != partner && null != source) {
                new com.example.psgITestAccountProvisioning001(partner, source);
                new com.example.psgITestAccountProvisioning002(partner, source);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

psgITest.xml is a properties file in the format below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
<dataset>
<partner>abc</partner>
<source>xyz</source>
</dataset>
</data>


Exception
================
org.testng.TestNGException:
```

The factory method class com.example.psgITestAccountProvisioning.runMultipleAccountProvisioningTestsWithDifferentUniversityPartners() threw an exception
    at org.testng.internal.FactoryMethod.invoke(FactoryMethod.java:93)
    at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.(TestNGClassFinder.java:140)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:409)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:235)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:205)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.(TestRunner.java:160)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG.java:141)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG.java:271)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:561)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:157)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.(SuiteRunner.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1299)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1286)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.testng.internal.FactoryMethod.invoke(FactoryMethod.java:82)
    ... 17 more

Any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the problem. The return type of the Factory method should be Object[]